# How to loop through a list of nodes and create new nodes based on the child nodes of those I'm looping through

Tags: xslt

This may be a basic question but this newbie has been struggling and Googling and hasn't been able to figure it out.

I have an xml document similar to this.

```
 <x99:events xmlns:x99="http://www.foo.com/x99" xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" pubdate="2012-05-29T11:14:14-06:00">
    <x99:event xl:href="event.xml?event_id=255918" id="foo" status="new">
        <x99:event_id>255918</x99:event_id>

        <x99:custom_attribute xmlns:x99="http://www.foo.com/x99" status="new">
            <x99:attribute_id>22</x99:attribute_id>
            <x99:attribute_value>hi there</x99:attribute_value>
        </x99:custom_attribute>

        <x99:custom_attribute xmlns:x99="http://www.foo.com/x99" status="new">
            <x99:attribute_id>26</x99:attribute_id>
            <x99:attribute_value>this is a test</x99:attribute_value>
        </x99:custom_attribute>

        <x99:custom_attribute xmlns:x99="http://www.foo.com/x99" status="new">
            <x99:attribute_id>12</x99:attribute_id>
            <x99:attribute_value>Yes</x99:attribute_value>
        </x99:custom_attribute>
    </x99:event>
</x99:events>
```

And I have some xsl that transforms the xml.

In my xsl I need to be able to loop through the custom_attribute nodes and, for each attribute_id I find I need to create a  node with some values based on child nodes of the custom_attribute node.

Here's my pseudo-code. I need something like this.

```
<xsl:for-each select="x99:custom_attribute">

    <xsl:when test="number(x99:attribute_id) = 22>
        <x99:text>You chose twenty two and your attribute value is <x99:attribute_value></x99:text>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:when test="number(x99:attribute_id) = 26>
        <x99:text>Twenty six is a great answer! and your attribute value is <x99:attribute_value></x99:text></x99:text>
    </xsl:when>

</xsl:for-each>
```

And here is my xsl.

My xsl skills are at the most basic level and my xml isn't much better either. Can some kind soul give me some advice? I'm in a bit over my head.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:b="http://www.someurl.com/b"
  xmlns:s="http://www.someurl.com/s"
  xmlns:c="http://foo.com/c"
  xmlns:x99="http://foo.com/x99"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xl x99">

    <xsl:param name="base_url" select="''" />
    <xsl:param name="session_id" select="''" />
    <xsl:param name="TaskDir" select="''" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="SendConfirmationEmail">
            <xsl:with-param name="EventID" select="/x99:events/x99:event/x99:event_id"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="SiteURL" select="'https://foobar.com/123Test/#details'" />
        </xsl:call-template>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="SendConfirmationEmail">
        <xsl:param name="EventID" select="''"/>

        <xsl:result-document>
            <schedule>
                <job>
                    <name>Email Confirmation</name>
                    <active>T</active>
                    <http>
                        <body>
                            <x99:email xmlns:x99="http://foo.com/x99">
                                <x99:mail>
                                    <x99:body>

                                        <x99:text>Your event ID is <xsl:value-of select="$EventID"/></x99:text>


                                        // I want to be able to loop through my x99:attribute_id values here and create new x99:text nodes.


                                    </x99:body>
                                </x99:mail>
                            </x99:email>
                        </body>
                    </http>
                </job>
            </schedule>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So frankly I need to know how to...

- Loop through the custom_attribute nodes and for each node create a x99:text node that contains
- a string based on the value of the child attribute_id
- the contents of the attribute_value node

Comment: You need to show the output XML you want to get from the input you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of using a named template with parameters as if you were programming in FORTRAN using CALL to invoke subroutines, just define a template to handle the `event_id` element, such as `<xsl:template match="event_id">`. I assume you mean `html`, not `http`. You'll need to specify a `href` attribute on the `<xsl:result-document>` element so it knows where to put the document. You're apparently writing elements into your HTML from the x99 namespace--is that really what you want to do?

With regard to "looping" over the attribute elements, in an XSLT mindset it would be preferable to say "process" them. Under `<x99:text>` add a `<xsl:apply-templates/>` element, then define a template to handle the custom attribute elements (`<xsl:template match="x99:custom-attribute">`. Within that template, place something like what you have within the `for-each` of your pseudo-code, except that instead of saying `number(x99:attribute_id)` you'll just want `number(.)` since we are already at that node. However, note that `<xsl:when>` elements can only go within a `<xsl:choose>`.